# Why chasing team allowed to bat first in super over?

Tags: rules, cricket, tie-breaker

**Super Over** is the concept introduced in the T20 leagues to decide the winner of a tied game. It is basically a one over match with only two allowed wickets to the batting side. Why is it that the chasing team is allowed to bat first in super over?

Is there any specific reason or logic behind that rule?

Comment: I'm not so sure it's "allowed" to bat first so much as "compelled" to bat first. All other things being equal, it's generally considered an advantage to be chasing in a limited overs match due to knowing what score you need to get - and I imagine that's even more significant in a one over match.

Comment: It depends on the abilities of batsmen, bowlers, their mental capabilities, etc. For example for team like zimbawe even a score of 10 will b difficult to chase against england. So I don't think chasing is pretty good in one over eliminator. To make logic in super over, there should be either toss or the logic I bring in earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyse two options as to why the chasing team bats first in super over.

1. The team that won the toss chose to bat first, but failed to win the match even with the advantage of toss. So exactly the opposite decision is imposed on the team in super over, as such the team has to chase the target in super over.
2. The team that won the toss chose to field first. So their decision is to chase down the target and failed even with the advantage of toss. So exactly the opposite decision is imposed on the team.

I believe this is because the team that scored without the advantage of the toss have a superior position in the draw than the one who got into the position with the toss. The batting order is reversed on the belief that the superior team is given a priority in conjunction with oppononent's previous decision.

Comment: Yes it has some logic I think

Comment: Do you have any references to back this up, or is this just your opinion?

Comment: It's my opinion only. I searched for a convincing reason. But didn't get one. That's why raised here.

Comment: The 2 points you have listed does make sense. However the last para is rather confusing/misleading as it is based on the assumption that "advantage of the toss" means batting first, which is not always true. +1 for the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another advantage that lies in allowing chasing team to bat first in super over is saving time and efforts because the fielding team is ready to field again soon after innings end as all 11 players are in the ground in fielding and bowling gears while on the other end, chasing team is ready to bat again as their players are already in the stands. 1 over gives sufficient time to all those players to get themselves ready to field and bowl again.

Comment: The innings changeover in Test match cricket happens in 10 mins or 2 overs. Don't think that can be a valid logic

Comment: In every match, the time for the whole match is decided in which official should end match due to many many reasons. Super over takes extra time, that's why it's very crucial to save each and every second. The reason provided in the answer is not the core reason. I have just explained another need that lies in the batting first of chasing team

Answer (score -1):

Chasing team always batting first due to minimize the time.
Because toss will also take time when bowling side batting first then padding for a batsma also take time.So chasing side always batting first

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers.